# Understanding how WebApi routes requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am new to WebApi and I followed this tutorial https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Everything works as expected - I have 2 endpoints

```
api/products
api/products/id
```

What I am trying to understand is how they relate to the methods defined in my controller.

For example, when I hit the api/products endpoint the action which runs is called GetAllProducts

And when I hit the api/products/id endpoint the action which runs is called GetProduct

So how does the WebApi engine know to direct the user to those endpoints?

My WebapiConfig.cs is

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Controller:

```
Product[] products = new Product[]
{
    new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
    new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
    new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
};

public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    return products;
}

public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
{
    var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(product);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: I expect it goes by the signature of your methods. You have two endpoints; one takes an id parameter, the other doesn't. You have two functions in your controller; one takes an id parameter, the other doesn't. It doesn't take too much processing power to figure that one out :).

Comment: Yes but if I had other endpoints, one which also takes an id, how does it know which one to route to? Is there anywhere which describes this, instead of sarcasm?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Not helpful at all, you're not answering what HAPPENS to make it work, which is what OP wants to know, and it's a good question.

Comment: @D.Foley *you're not answering* ...which is why it's a comment. It was a guess based on years of experience using ASP.NET Web API. And as it turns out, a correct guess.

Comment: @andrewb It wasn't sarcasm; it was a comment about the ease with which the routing service can guess at which function to use. You can test the use of other endpoints by adding another function which has the same signature to your controller and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find this link very illuminating:

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection

> To select an action, it looks at the following:
>
> The HTTP method of the request.
>
> The "{action}" placeholder in the route template, if present.
>
> The parameters of the actions on the controller.

In your case, it's the last option that dictates which method is invoked -- as Mike said in his comment, it's based on the signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is controlled as how the routing is defined... 
As you can see that the ID param is optional.. so whenever you hit request api/products - your request will be matched against the routing table and it sees that ID is not passed which is ok because
it is defined as optional... so your method GetAllProducts is invoked....

whereas if you pass the ID in url... you are explicitely setting up the optional param which is again matching with your routing... and thus you get product detail of specified id.